# The boredom of Mr. Goldy

Tags: story, music

"Today is a lame day," stated Mr. Goldy. Indeed, this poor man is quite lonely as he lost his brother years ago. That was a terrible time for him. His brother was a very important part of his life, and his only friend.

To kill time, Mr. Goldy decided to watch some TV. "Bah, not this new Music channel. This is pure bollocks.  In my time we used to listen to real music." Tears in his eyes, he decided to switch off the TV and go to his bedroom. With a precise movement due to the number of times he made this action, Mr. Goldy unfolded the old piece of paper reposed on the desk and started to read it, once again:

> Dear brother, if you are reading this I am already gone.
>    War will never change, neither will humans.
>    But You must not be sad, think about the good times!
>    Remember Big Daddy at the military camp? That guy was so strong we use to called him the cloud!

At that moment, Mr. Goldy started smiling, his heart full of joy; comforted by the first half of the letter. He knew that worrying wouldn't help him and continued to read:

> And you should not forget our youth either!
>      When we used to go down to the River near our house and play with Mum!
>      When we played cops and robbers, ran into the village and got lost!
>      And this, my brother, is why you should stay happy. Turn your old radio on, put our favorite disk in, and relax to the music.

After reading the letter one more time, Mr. Goldy turned his old radio on, put a disk in, and forgot all of his problems as music played.

**What disk was Mr. Goldy listening to?** All the answers are contained within the text. There is only one solution and it is unambiguous.

(PS: This is my first story, There might be a lot of English / grammar faults, I would appreciate it a lot if a native speaker or someone better than me at English could correct all of the mistakes I've made)

Hint :

> In this text, there are relations to every song of the desired album, either directly by the title of the song, or by its lyrics.

Second Hint :

> The intended album has 9 songs, six or seven of which are quite explicit in the text, the other two or three are a bit more subtle.

One last hint cause it looks too hard :

> Dear brother, if you are reading this I am already gone.
>  War will never change, neither will humans.
>
>
>  These lines cover both the album name and last of the album (which have the same name)

Comment: Upper case on River and You not beginning sentences.  Is this intentional?  I'm also assuming Big Daddy is being used as a proper noun.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore "Upper case on River and You not beginning sentences." The words Never and Mum as well.

Comment: Actually, I took Never as coming after a period.  which would be more correct.  Mum is used as a proper noun I believe.

Comment: Speculation: Judging by other questions from the same user, I would say it's something about a classic rock band/song. Somewhere in there with Led Zeppelin or Deep Purple. Also the name "Goldy" might suggest the same thing.

Comment: Yeh, Mum is used as a proper noun, and never is after the comma, maybe I made a mistake. The one on River and You are little hints, but not too big of a deal. And yeh, Marius is on a good track.

Comment: While not a mistake, I grew up with "cops and robbers" rather than "policeman and thief".

Comment: I just did my best at traduction ^^ but it doesn't change the answer and this sentence does not really help. I'll correct it if it sounds better :)

Comment: Nope, that's not it, and as I said you can cover every song of the album, so it is not Jhonny cash. Let me put some hint.

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Are the hints in the same order as the songs on the album?

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer. Is the album in English, or do I have to learn a new language (German for example :D) ?

Comment: it is in english, and it is quite famous (both the band and the album)

Comment: Shouldn't [tag:knowledge] be added as tags?

Comment: Sorry question_asker, didn't see your question ! The songs are not in the album order, but if you find one or two songs you'll find the whole album easily :)

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Thank you! I have an idea for the album but I can't make all the clues work yet

Comment: I have edited the grammer of this, please tell me if it no longer fits your intent, you can revert back to the last edit.

Comment: Thanks, as I said I welcome any grammar edit, my english is quite meh :)

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Re: your last hint - is that the same title in both cases (song title and album title are the same), or are there two different titles?

Comment: It is the same, let me edit that !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it...?

> Dire Straits - Brothers in Arms
>
>  There are continuous references to the war in the album. As the lyrics of the song "Brothers in Arms" says "[...] We're fools to make war, On our brothers in arms". The lyrics for "Money for Nothing" is talking about MTV, as Mr. Goldy says "Bah, not this new Music channel.[...]". Mr. Goldy and his brother use to go for a "Ride Across the River" and remember how Big Daddy, "The Man's Too Strong".
>
>    Tracking list - "Brothers in Arms"
>
>  1. "So Far Away"
>  2. "Money for Nothing"
>  3. "Walk of Life"
>  4. "Your Latest Trick"
>  5. "Why Worry"
>  6. "Ride Across the River"
>  7. "The Man's Too Strong"
>  8. "One World"
>  9. "Brothers in Arms"
>
>  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers_in_Arms_(Dire_Straits_album)#Track_listings

Comment: This seems correct, but please expand your answer and explain how each song is connected.

Comment: A lot of it fits, but some things, like "the cloud," didn't make sense when I looked at it.

Comment: There was quite a bug, I didn't see it earlier, good job, but can you explain a bit more? you lack some detail for some songs :)

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer I will take a deeper look when I arrive home after work (14.50 here in Vienna just now). But it took me quite a lot to figure out some of the songs. Once I have the album I could explain some songs. But I will take a look to the rest later. Thanks for the challenge, it was very fun (my first one) :)

Comment: Well, congrats, I hope you enjoyed it! Thanks for working on it!

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Am I still able to "win" the bounty?

Comment: yes, but there is time before I can give you the points, I'll give you when the site will allow me to!